# How can i put this 4 images inside of 1 image?

Tags: html, css, image, row, overlapping

I am stuck at the moment to put this 4 images (in the same row) inside of the div with image.

Html:

```css
.iniciRo img {
  width: 100%;
}

.iniciRo .coluna img {
  width: 270px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.iniciRo>div {
  padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
}

.iniciRo .row>div {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.coluna {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="iniciRo">
  <img src="assets/images/Rodape/backbot.png">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="coluna">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/Rodape/visitas-escolas.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="coluna">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/Rodape/rafc.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="coluna">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/Rodape/rioavetv.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="coluna">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/Rodape/galeri.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to use z-index but nothing happened.
Any help is going to be appreciated, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
coluna img {
  position: relative;   
  padding: 50em;
}

.iniciRo img{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.iniciRo > div{
    padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
}

.iniciRo .row > div{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.coluna{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30em;

}

.row{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 75em;
  clear: both;
}
```

In other words you want `position: absolute` for the iniciRo img, `position: relative` for .row, and the use of `flexbox` for .row. [Here's a JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pxyw685h/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Flexbox css code

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
</div>


    .flex-container{
    display:flex;
    }
   .flex-container div {
     flex:1;
    margin:5px; 
   }
  img {
   width:100%;
   }
```